# Is it possible to call a ColdFusion web service in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, web-services, coldfusion

I made a web service in ColdFusion. I can successfully call this service, with dynamic parameters, from C#. However, I am unable to call this service from iPhone Xcode. The response shows an operation failed error. So how can I consume this service from Xcode?

Comment: can you post web service link ...

Comment: actually my webservice running on local its not a live...neverthless i show you format 'http://localhost/webservice/login.cfc?wsdl'

Comment: still localhost here you execute it locally can you host it on any server so i can help you on it

Comment: are you able to consume the ws with another client application ? like your browser for example :), or wsget or curl ... something.

Comment: my webservice needs to access database which is too large so right now its not possible to host it on server but i can make demo service which doesnt need any database.what do u say about it then will you help me?

Comment: yes i can consume coldfusion ws from my C#.net application with post param @YvesLeBorg

Comment: sorry, i really meant one from the list i suggested ... ie to exclude the fact that .net/c# could cause this to work, albeit not quite standard in HTTP protocol handling (seen in the past). You could 'dump' the request string from your c# client and see if one of the clients above can use the same request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have more than one application using a Coldfusion component via Xcode on an iPhone. Mostly consuming financial data. I believe we use the a call like:

```
action.cfc?method=blah&param1=blah&param2=blah
```

with a return format of either XML or json - so on the Xcode end of it we are using a parser for one of those technologies to deserialize the object.